# Localising ASP.NET MVC JQuery Validation on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, localization

I am developing a website to support both Arabic and English. Now, when on the development I only need to use `DisplayAttribute` to localize field names and set the thread to the appropriate culture, and then ASP.NET generates a localized error message using my `DispalyAttribute` names.

However, when deploying on Azure, and when I switch to Arabic, everything is localized correctly but error messages. In which the names are localized but the error itself is in English.

[image]

I could use `ErrorMessageResourceType` explicitly, but would like to know where is the discrepancy.

Note: I set thread culture at `Application_BeginRequest` of Global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little hack to know where the issue is. I created my own `ValidationAttribute` which basically reports current culture name instead of the error message. It turned out that the culture is properly set, and that it seems Azure *version* of `DataAnnotationResources` might not include Arabic.

[image]